# Ajax listener does not recognize the dynamically populated SelectOneMenu SelectItems

Tags: html, ajax, primefaces, javabeans

I have a Primefaces SelectOneMenu with two options(Mail or Report). When one of these is selected I update another SelectOneMenu with the corresponding data. For this I use ajax and a function in a bean and it works fine. When an item in the second SelectOneMenu is selected I want to fill in a Primeface Text Editor and an InputText with some data. Similar to the first SelectOneMenu I use an ajax listener which calls a function from my bean. The Problem is that the function (handleSelect) is not called when a dynamically populated item in the second SelectOneMenu is selected but it does get called when this SelectItem is clicked.

```
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
```

This leads me to believe that maybe the second SelectOneMenu does not acknowledge the dynamically populated items as SelectItem of its own.

Or maybe it has to do something with the initial loading or rather the loading during the runtime populating of the second SelectOneMenu?

Here my Html code

First SelectOneMenu

```
<h:form>
        <p:outputLabel for="@next" value=""  />                                            
        <p:selectOneMenu>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select one" itemValue=""/>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Mail Template" itemValue="Mail Template"/>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Report Template" itemValue="Report Template"/>
        <p:ajax event="itemSelect" update="selectTemplateForm:templateMenu, selectTemplateForm" listener="#{templateBean.mailOrReportHandler}"/> 
        </p:selectOneMenu>
</h:form>
```

Second SelectOneMenu

```
<h:form id="selectTemplateForm">
    <p:outputLabel for="@next" value=""  />
    <p:selectOneMenu id="templateMenu" filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains" value="mailTemplateBean.text">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{templateBean.templateSelectItemList}"/>
    <p:ajax event="itemSelect" update="editorForm:textEditor, editorForm:titleField" listener="#{templateBean.handleSelect}"/>
    </p:selectOneMenu>
</h:form>
```

editorForm is the id of the <h:form> tag in which the

```
 <p:textEditor id="textEditor">
```

and the

```
<p:inputText id="titleField"/>
```

are located.

I should add that populating these fields works as long as I only use the second SelectOneMenu with initially loaded SelectItems.

Any help is appreciated.